# Why do 2d vectors look weird when I'm watching them in debug mode?

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, codeblocks, 2d-vector

I've been scratching my head for ages trying to work out why my 2d vectors look like they're storing things in the wrong order, and have twice as many entries as they should. I'm watching them in debug mode using the "watches" window in codeblocks.

When I just outputted all the data to the terminal, it is infact in the correct order.

Why's it showing up so wrong in the watches window? Is it something to do with how it's actually stored?

EDIT:

here is an image of my Watches window showing the 2d vector. It is mostly empty, but I've just noticed that it says length = 12, capacity = 12 at the top. So it clearly knows it's not actually that long. The way the vectors constructed, ints between 0 and 999 should be in element 0, ints between 1000 and 1999 in element 1, ints between 2000 and 2999 in element 2, and so on until ints between 11000 to 11999 in element 11. So that int 6019 should definately not be in element 1! And isn't if I cout to terminal.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should show a picture of this + a small self contained code example that fills the arrays and your expected values. Otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: why the downvote? is it not a legit question? The picture contains the info needed. It is clear that the vector is indeed 12 elements long, but it is being displayed differently to how I would expect to read it. So the question is why?

Comment: The debugger is probably just not smart enough. It just sees a pointer to the vector's data, but doesn't know enough to realize the relationship between that data and the size member.

Comment: I take it back. It seems to be alternating between showing length and capacity of the sub-vectors as individual elements, that's complete nonsense.

Comment: That could make sense. But I'd of thought the latest GDB would be fairly smart. I don't however know much about the ins and outs of debuggers yet. Or could it be how codeblocks is interpreting the debuggers data?

Comment: Yeah, it's alternating, and then occasionally showing an element in the wrong place

Comment: Well, I don't use CodeBlocks or GDB, so cannot attest to the quality of either one.

Comment: The pointers used to hold your vector arrays are not terminated, so Codeblocks will continue to show data (non-existing vectors) until it discovers a termination point (null).  Codeblocks is a GREAT C++ IDE, but it only works with the code its given.   Are you storing pointers to vectors?

Comment: Nope, this vector was declared, initialised and filled in the same function I was in when I print screened this watches window, nothing else has happened to this vector. And to reiterate, when I cycle through the vectors within the vector and print all the data, showing the indexes aswell as the data, it's all in the right place

Comment: @zackery.fix Sorry, I almost forgot, I am not using pointers

Comment: @IronAttorney Could you create a Gist on GitHub that exposes the code you are using that gives you these results?  Also, make sure Codeblocks has a watch definition for vector.  You should see `Registered new type: STL Vector` in the Debugger output window.

Comment: @IronAttorney  And try this with only 10 items per vector.

Comment: @zackery.fix I'm not familiar enough with Github yet, but I will give that a go later. It is worth mentioning that I have noticed some of this behaviour with my multi dimensional vectors before. 1D vectors show up fine. The debugger is registering the new type: STL Vector

Comment: Encase it's important: Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1

Comment: I implemented the same instantiation that you describe, and I get expected watches.  Each vector is nested exactly as I would imagine the data to look.  Maybe something this is a wxWindows bug on Ubuntu, I can't imagine the sources for Codeblocks doing anything different for this part of the IDE for a different platform. Ill check it out, but I suggest going to the Codeblocks forum and seeing if this is a known issue, or expected behaviour.

Comment: Ok cool, good idea! Thanks for the time testing this for me.